# How to set Thickness value for Margin in doubleanimation (code not XAML)

Tags: c#, wpf

i want to use animation to move an object in `WPF`.
what i know to do that is `From` and `To` property
but its not working because they take type double and Margin is type Thickness. 
i also used `SetValue` as u see

```
            DoubleAnimation lockation = new DoubleAnimation();
        lockation.SetValue(MarginProperty, new Thickness(423, 219, -5, -5));
        lockation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
        image.BeginAnimation(Image.MarginProperty, lockation);
```

but its not working too.
what should i do?

Comment: If your Image is in a Canvas, you may also consider animating the Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top properties, which are of type double.

Comment: If you want to animate a Thickness, use a [ThicknessAnimation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.thicknessanimation(v=vs.110).aspx)